# Acess Violation Exception while casting

Tags: c++, firebreath

I want to cast FB::variant to FB::JSObjectPtr. below is my code

```
void PluginAPI::Test(FB::variant testVariant)
 {
     FB::JSObjectPtr jsObject=testVariant.convert_cast< FB::JSObjectPtr>();
 }
```

the above casting throws the Access violation Exception. Please let me know for the solution.

Comment: How are `FB::variant` and `FB::JSObjectPtr` defined?

Comment: Test(FB::variant testVariant) is called from JavaScript & testVariant is the JavaScript object.

Comment: What you mean by `javascript object` then? Show us the code and possible reason, not only the problem.

Comment: @herohyuongtao and Victor don't downvote the question just because you don't know FireBreath; to someone familiar with FireBreath the answers to your questions are obvious.  Those are FireBreath types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why an access violation exception would be thrown, but in general the most likely reason for this would be that it isn't actually a javascript object that is getting passed in.

Why are you doing a convert_cast inside the function?  Just rewrite the function to:

```
void PluginAPI::Test(const FB::JSObjectPtr& jsObject)
{
    // use it here
}
```